# Red5 Flash RTMPT Stream Disconnection over reverse proxy

Tags: flash, reverse-proxy, red5

I am using the RED5 Media Server in order to create a teleconferencing application. Due to project constraints I am forced to use `RTMPT` which of course is a suboptimal solution.

My production environment has a **reverse proxy** that forwards requests to the **internal Red5 server**. I have observed that when I am **behind the reverse proxy**, for some reason **the TCP connection is suddenly stopped**, and Broadcasting is interrupted. The same does not occur in a similar environment where there is no **Reverse Proxy** and the `Red5 Server` is hit directly. Additionally, I dont have disconnections with `RTMP` either.

I have checked for too many open `TCP` connections, but this doesn't seem to be the case since these close relatively quick and rarely go over 100 concurrent.

Other observations the following.
- Worse network conditions seem to expedite the occurrence of the problem.
- When using chrome the disconnections are less frequent than IE or Firefox.

Any ideas?